# Rails form_with to select values from model1 for model2 with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord, erb

I am new to Rails and working on a blog project.

I have *articles* and *categories*. Each *article* can have multiple *categories* and each *category* can belong to multiple *articles*.
I also have a join table *articles_categories*

My migrations:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateArticlesCategoriesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :articles, :categories do |t|
      t.index :article_id
      t.index :category_id
    end
  end
end
```

My model associations:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

This all makes sense so far.
What I am struggling with now, is how do I add categories when creating a new Article? I want to be able to select pre-defined categories from a list (stored in Category table) through a form.

What model and/or URL (if any) do I use in the form_with helper?
Is the following anywhere close?

```
<% form_with model: ???, url: ??? do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you define @article in new and create controller actions? You need to use this variable in form_with, and you can remove url option in this case. Use f.select instead of f.collection_select

Comment: Thanks a mil @Vasilisa. This worked!
I do define `@article` in new and create articles_controller actions so could use this as suggested.